# Rails: No CRUD delete shortcut path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm going through the Rails ["Getting Started"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#updating-articles) guide and noticed what seems like an inconsistency with shortcuts. See the following code:

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
<tr>
  <td><%= article.title %></td>
  <td><%= article.text %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Show', article_path(article) %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article) %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', article_path(article), 
  method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
</tr>
```

We have an `article_path` shortcut for show, and `edit_article_path` shortcut for CRUD update. However, the syntax changes and to delete, we have to add `method: :delete` to the show path.

Is there a methodology-related or technical reason why there is no `delete_article_path`?

Comment: No, there is not. It's pure convention.

Answer (score 2):

There is!

The methodology is based on mapping HTTP request methods and URLs to the ideas of CRUD.

[The Rails guides say](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions):

> In Rails, a resourceful route provides a mapping between HTTP verbs and URLs to controller actions. By convention, each action also maps to a specific CRUD operation in a database. A single entry in the routing file, such as:
>
> ```
> resources :photos
> ```
>
> creates seven different routes in your application, all mapping to the Photos controller:
>
> ```
> HTTP Verb     Path               Controller#Action    Used for
> GET           /photos            photos#index         display a list of all photos
> GET           /photos/new        photos#new           return an HTML form for creating a new photo
> POST          /photos            photos#create        create a new photo
> GET           /photos/:id        photos#show          display a specific photo
> GET           /photos/:id/edit   photos#edit          return an HTML form for editing a photo
> PATCH/PUT     /photos/:id        photos#update        update a specific photo
> DELETE        /photos/:id        photos#destroy       delete a specific photo
> ```
>
> Because the router uses the HTTP verb and URL to match inbound requests, four URLs map to seven different actions.

So Rails uses the HTTP verb and URL to match requests. There is no HTTP verb that by any convention means to see a resource to edit it, so we get the `edit_article_path(article)`. However for the other actions, like show, destroy, and update, the same URL is used with different HTTP verbs (GET, DELETE and PATCH/PUT).

**[edit]**

There is only a need to use the `method: :verb` format when paths are duplicated among verbs. The duplicated paths for the default set of routes for resources are, using the photos example from the docs, `/photos` (GET and POST) and `/photos/:id` (GET, PATCH/PUT and DELETE).

The usage of these paths also tends to imply their verb. So, when you create a link to the `photos_path` (`/photos`) or `photo_path` (`/photos/:id`), a link is implicitly a GET so the GET form will be returned.

On the other hand, if you have a `@photo` object without an ID and use it in a form, it is implicitly a POST to create that object. If you have a `@photo` object with an ID in a form then you are likely updating it, so the verb is PATCH.

As @hashrocket said in the comments, the only real non implicit use is when creating a destroy link and you have to point out that the link isn't just supposed to GET the resource, but DELETE it instead.

Finally, each individual path has a method for it and is why you need to provide the verb to disambiguate. The methods are:

```
Path method      Path   
photos_path      /photos 
new_photos_path  /photos/new
photo_path       /photos/:id
edit_photo_path  /photos/:id/edit
```

The only reason to use a different method for the path itself is that you are pointing at a unique path.

Comment: That makes sense for `new_photos_path`, but then why don't things like `method :update` for things with an HTTP verb? Is that just assumed by a form submit? Can you make more clear the distinction between when `method :verb` is needed, and a shortcut like `edit_photos_path` will suffice?

Comment: The only time you need method :verb is for deletion. Rails figures out the rest by how you use them.

Comment: Updated my answer with some more explanation of the available paths.